# How to avoid Python 2.7 64-bit Error: 000732:

Tags: arcpy, network-analyst, error-000732, 64bit

I have a Python script that creates a service area with the Network Analyst extension, (after building ND with [Add GTFS to a Network Dataset](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=0fa52a75d9ba4abcad6b88bb6285fae1))

The Network Dataset is in GDB

When I'm running the script with ArcMap it works, but when I'm running the script standalone it starts the Progress and then I have an out of memory error (it is caching a large database).

[image]

I installed the 64-bit background geoprocessing and I tried to run the same script using C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.5\python.exe but I receive 
`"Error: 000732: Dataset does not exist or is not supported"`. I tried some different ways to insert the path of the network data set and didn't work.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import os


try:
#Check out the Network Analyst extension license
 arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Network")

#Set environment settings
 env.workspace = r"D:\GTFS\GTFS_ND.gdb"
 env.overwriteOutput = True

#Set local variables
 inNetworkDataset = os.path.join("D:\GTFS\GTFS_ND.gdb","GTFS\GTFS_ND")
 outNALayerName = "ServiceArea"
 impedanceAttribute = "TravelTime"
 inFacilities = "locetion\Test"
 outLayerFile = os.path.join("D:\GTFS\scripts" ,outNALayerName + ".lyr"


 outNALayer = arcpy.na.MakeServiceAreaLayer(inNetworkDataset, outNALayerName,
                              impedanceAttribute, "TRAVEL_TO", "60",
                              "SIMPLE_POLYS", "NO_MERGE", "RINGS",
                              excluded_source_name = ["Connectors_Stops2Streets", "TransitLines"],time_of_day= "1/1/1900 10:30 AM" )
```

in 64 bit I get the error:

```
Erorr 00732: Input Analysis Network: Dataset GTFS/GTFS_ND dose not exist or is not supported
```

What is wrong?

**EDIT**

I tested the script with other ND (With 64-bit ) and it work.
The problem is only in The ND that use GTFS and built step by step with this guide:
https://github.com/Esri/public-transit-tools/blob/master/add-GTFS-to-a-network-dataset/UsersGuide.md

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify what data are you using. It seems unlikely the standalone 32-bit Python would run out of memory faster than ArcMap.

Comment: We need the actual storage format -- File geodatabase? Personal geodatabase? Please provide the relevant chunk of Python in the body of the question.

Comment: I edit  the question

Comment: Check your `inNetworkDataset` variable. Here arcpy is looking for `GTFS/GTFS_ND` in your workspace which corresponds to `r"D:\GTFS\GTFS_ND.gdb\GTFS/GTFS_ND`.

Comment: i fix it, still not work

Comment: There is also a syntax issue with  `outLayerFile = "D:\GTFS\scripts" + "\" + outNALayerName + ".lyr"`. `\"` is recognoized as an embedded double quote and opens a string instead of closing it. Write `"D:\GTFS\scripts\" + outNALayerName + ".lyr"`, or even better, us `os.path.join()` to join path parts: `import os ... os.path.join(r"D:\GTFS\scripts", outNALayerName + ".lyr")`

Comment: the path is not the issue, the sample above is one of various way that i tried to get it work , i changed the syntax an used os.path.join and still i get the message:"Erorr 00732: Input Analysis Network: Dataset D:\GTFS\GTFS_ND.gdb\GTF\GTFS_ND dose not exist or is not supported" . but the same syntax in 32bit start the Progresss